# Contacts framework doesn't request for access when needed

Tags: ios, swift

This is what I have so far:

```
private let contactStore = CNContactStore()

private func requestAccessForContacts() {

    switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts) {
    case .Denied, .NotDetermined:

        contactStore.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts, completionHandler: { access, error in

            if access {
                print("super")
            } else {
                print("problem")
            }
        })
    case .Authorized:
        print("ok")
    case .Restricted:
        print("restricted")
    }
}
```

The `problem` is printed on console, but nothing is displayed on screen, no request for access. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works; I was able to replicate the problem by first rejecting access to contact and re-running the app.

Once you have disallowed access, subsequent running of the app would log **"problem"** without displaying any request window.

If one wanted to see this request window again after denying, one could, 
however, go to 
"***Settings***" -> "***Reset***" and click "***Reset Location And Privacy***" in the simulator.

After having done so, the next time you run the app, a request window would pop up again.